# How to keep behavior subject data on page reload

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-services, behaviorsubject

I have a component (properties.component.html) that renders real estate properties. When a user clicks on a specific property, I set a Behavior Subject equal to this property.

```
private property = new BehaviorSubject<Property>();

setProperty(property) {
  this.property.next(property);
}
```

The component (property.component.html) renders just fine with the data returned from the observable in the service from the Behavior Subject.

```
this.propertyService.getProperty()
  .subscribe((property) => {
     this.currentProperty = property;
  })
```

My issue: when the page reloads, the Behavior Subject is now 'empty?' with no data because the .next(property) gets called in properties.component.html on a click.

How can an application hold data on page refresh/reload?

Another poster mentions storing the property in localStorage as a stringified JSON.  If that's the solution, then how can a user access this specific property by directly visiting https://www.myapp.com/property/1234?

Comment: Note that you can't retain data in observable and extended objects from observable classes like subject and behavior subject when the page reloads, in that case, you supposed to retain your data via local storage or a state management  library like NGRX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution, but you can do something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class PropertyService {

    private property = new ReplaySubject<Property>(1);

    constructor() {
        let storedProp = localStorage.get('storedProp');
        if (storedProp)
            this.setProperty(JSON.parse(storedProp), false);
    }

    setProperty(property: Property, storeProp: boolean = false) {
        if (storeProp)
            localStorage.set('storedProp', JSON.stringify(property));
        this.property.next(property);
    }

    getProperty() {
        return this.property;
    }
}
```

The subscriber would get the value whenever it subscribes to proptery through getProperty().subscribe().

Comment: Is the difference between ReplaySubject and BehaviorSubject important here?

Comment: The difference is that ReplaySubject replays the value to the subscriber if the subscription is done after the value has been emitted. In this case this can be a possibility since we are emitting the value straight away in PropertyService. If the subscription is made before the value has been emitted on a BehaviourSubject it won't get through.

Comment: Ok. this worked but I don't know why.  Could you go into more detail about how the subscription is made before the value is emitted on behaviorSubject?  Please!

Answer (score 0):

Like others have mentioned you can use localStorage to solve this. I did something similar to this by using the queryParams property of route.

`import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'`

```
routeSubscription!: Subscription
paramData: number    //since desired property in url is a number (1234)`

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute)
{ 
    this.routeSubscription = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.paramData = params.data    //params.data holds value 1234
});
```

}`

After storing the parameters in a variable I called a function with paramData as the argument to load the appropriate data from a post (or get) httpClient